Seeking advice for transitioning to full remote work due to family responsibilities
I am a web designer and developer since many years for local clients. I work alone in a home office ad have some interaction with few local freelance collegues for occasional collaborations or mutual help.
I'm looking for advice on how to successfully transition to a fully remote job, since in last years things have changed a lot for me, I need to stay home to manage and care for elderly parents and a brother with a disability, which makes it necessary for me to be present, and that increased over time, and will increase more and more.
I can no longer travel for stay away full days or attend in-person meetings as I used to, sometimes clients or collegues invites me to stay at their offices full time, have work-lunches or similar, but for me is a struggle more than a pleasure, thinking about all other duties I have at home.
I was seeking for professional support and help for the family situation, but I couldn't find anything or that I can afford.
I wish to transition to a full remote position, but I’ve been struggling to find opportunities. I’ve tried various freelancing sites, but it's difficult to compete with individuals from other countries who work for extremely low rates, I couldn't even find a single job from there, even to start.
I am also ready to completely change my job or activity, since it will provide a normal income for my needs, at this very moment I don't care about job itself.
I am not taking into any possibility to go to work full time as employee in some other company or office.

Based on your experience in tech, it seems to me that you will be able to get a remote job fairly easily. You can also continue freelancing on platforms like Upwork, Fiverr, Freelancer. Another amazing platform for remote jobs/projects is Toptal.
Given your experience as a web designer and developer, I suggest creating a polished portfolio showcasing the projects you have developed. Include recent projects and the technologies you have used.
In case you're more inclined towards a full-time remote job, you can start searching for remote jobs on various platforms online. One of the common ones is LinkedIn, where you can find hundreds of remote jobs (in your country and abroad). Another one is Indeed (Another platform for finding remote jobs)
I hope these details will help, still please do ask if you have more queries.
